# List view crashing

Tags: android

I am trying to create `ListView` and fill it with data , but when i launch the application crashes and shows me a message

> Unfortunately,… has stopped.

I am trying to do this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

---

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] actions = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> value = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                R.id.mylist, actions);


        ListView  v = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        v.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        v.setAdapter(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

---

log

```
08-08 15:19:47.364: E/Trace(604): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-08 15:19:47.945: I/Choreographer(604): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-08 15:19:47.965: D/AndroidRuntime(604): Shutting down VM
08-08 15:19:47.995: W/dalvikvm(604): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-08 15:19:48.015: E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 15:19:51.895: I/Process(604): Sending signal. PID: 604 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> value = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.mylist, actions);
```

To this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> value = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, actions);

//OR

ArrayAdapter<String> value = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       android.R.id.text1, actions);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NullPointerException because of your  ArrayAdapter constructor , the third parameter should be the TextView inside the layout (2nd parameter) , change it to `android.R.id.text1`  and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your misused its constructor.

Try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> value = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, actions);
```

In [ArrayAdapter Documentaion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), the third parameter should be an ID of a `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor for the arrayadapter is incorrect.

ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                R.id.mylist, actions);

I believe R.id.mylist is the identifier for the listview? With this constructor it is actually expecting the identifier of the textview that is part of the layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Answer (score -1):

It seem that your layout is out of scope of the code and thus cannot be loaded. When you check the log you can see the error "NullPointerException" which indicates that you are trying to access an object that does not exist.

Probably it is the line

```
ListView  v = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
```

that is not creating the object as you expect. If you put a breakpoint on this line you will see that is is null and by stepping to the next line

```
v.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

you will see that the exception occurs here.

Please check your references and how you invoke the layout in order to get the proper object loading.